# Multiple return in one function (javascript)

Tags: javascript

```
function myFunction() {
    if (condition)
        return a;
    return b;
}
```

In this case if the condition is `true`, both `a` and `b` will be returned or only `a` is returned.

Comment: return a tuple, or class

Comment: only a will be returned as The return statement stops the execution of a function

Comment: do somthing like that return [a, b];  or  like that return {
        a: a,
        b: b    };

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a compiler for your source code run.

Comment: For such a trivial question, it was way faster to build a simple test case than asking for an answer here…

Answer (score 1):

If the condition is true, only a is returned.

No curly brace means only the next statement is exectuted after the if.

Answer (score 0):

Only the first return is executed, then the flow is returned in the case the if condition is met..

Answer (score 0):

Try it yourself like below in browser console.

```
(function()
{
var f1= function(condition){
  if(condition>1)
     return "a"
     return "b"
    };  

var result=  f1(3)
console.log(result)

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

you can return result as array or object 
example:

```
function myFunction()
{
    if (condition){ 
        return [a,b]; 
    }else{ 
        return [b]; 
    } 
 }
```